# Programmatically Closing React Native Swipe List View

Tags: react-native

I'm using `react-native-swipe-list-view` (https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view) in my React Native app and I'm trying to close rows programmatically.

Once the user swipes to the right or left and clicks the button there, I call a function to make API calls and handle a few things. This is where I also try to close the row programmatically. This is working ONLY for the last item in the list. Anything above it, the row stays open.

I do hit my `handleClickUpdateItemStatus()` function and the API call works fine but as I said, only the last item in the list will close. Anything above that one stays open even though all the other code in the function work fine.

My code looks like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.handleClickUpdateItemStatus = this.handleClickUpdateItemStatus.bind(this);
   }

   handleClickUpdateItemStatus(itemId, value) {
      this._swipeListView.safeCloseOpenRow();
      // Call my API to update item status
   }
   render() {
     return(
        <Container>
           <SwipeListView
                ref={ref => this._swipeListView = ref}
                data={this.props.items}
                ... // Omitted for brevity />
        </Container>
      );
   }
}
```

Any idea what's causing this?

Comment: Got help from library author on GitHub. I had omitted the `keyExtractor` which was causing the issue. Simply added `keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}` to `<SwipeListView>` and it fixed the issue. Here's the issue and the answer I received on GitHub: https://github.com/jemise111/react-native-swipe-list-view/issues/467